# How to get Xwindows background color information

Tags: x11, xorg, xterm

I tried xrdb -query -all, appres XTerm xterm commands. but i could not get any background color information. I saw the manpage, the default Xwindow background color is white. But when i started my xwindows application, it will open with CornFlower blue background. I tried to look in the Xresources, Xdefaults, Xinitrc, and then app-defaults directory. But i could not get background related stuff. Please help me to figure out the background color information where it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) (rather than some terminal which emulates xterm), there are two background colors to consider:

- the default background for the terminal window
- the current color which might be set using escape sequences

Using `appres XTerm`, I might see these background resources:

```
*fontMenu*background:      AntiqueWhite   
*VT100.scrollbar.background:        gray60
*VT100*background:  black
*SimpleMenu*background:     AntiqueWhite
*mainMenu*background:       AntiqueWhite
*tekMenu*background:        AntiqueWhite
*form.background:   AntiqueWhite
*vtMenu*background: AntiqueWhite
*Form.menubar.background:   AntiqueWhite
*Form.menubar*background:   AntiqueWhite
*Form.background:   AntiqueWhite
```

The `VT100` one is what you would look for, for the *default background*.  If you used the `uxterm` script, you would use `appres UXTerm` to get similar information.

Colors set with escape sequences do not show up in the output from `appres`.  There are escape sequences (see [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)) to set and *query* these values.  A few programs such as [`xtermcontrol`](http://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/) and [`xtermset`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clts/) make it simple to do this from a script, e.g.,

```
$ xtermcontrol --get-bg
rgb:0000/0000/0000
```